# Stuck with shortest path in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I've been working for days in this project where (as the title says), I have to create an array with a given graph with nodes and then find the shortest path from a "source" to a "target".

I wrote all the methods given except for the "findPath" which obviously finds the shortest path from node A to node B. I tried to wrote a simple code using recursion but it doesn't work as i'd...

I know where are the problems but i really don't know how to fix them.

Here's the array ("path") with all the linked nodes:

My input:

- `source: 0`
- `target: 9`

My set:

```
    (0, 0)
    (0, 1)
    (1, 2)
    (2, 1)
    (2, 3)
    (3, 4)
    (2, 5)
    (5, 6)
    (6, 4)
    (2, 7)
    (2, 8)
    (8, 9)
```

This should be the method that finds the shortest path:

```java
    public void findPath(Integer[][] path, int rowPath, int colPath, Integer[][] possiblePath, int colPoss, int rowPoss, int cont, Integer[] distance, int topDist) {
        if(path[rowPath][colPath+1] == path[rowPath+1][colPath]){
            possiblePath[rowPoss][colPoss] = path[rowPath][colPath+1];
            colPoss++;
            rowPath++;
            cont++;
            findPath(path, rowPath, colPath, possiblePath, colPoss, rowPoss, cont, distance, topDist);
        }else {
            distance[topDist] = cont;
            topDist++;
            rowPoss++;
            rowPath = 0;
            colPoss = 0;
            if (rowPoss == 5) return;
            findPath(path, rowPath, colPath, possiblePath, colPoss, rowPoss, cont, distance, topDist);
        }
    }
```

For those who're asking why the recursive method stops when `rowPoss` reaches `5`, it's because i know that in the primitive array there are a maximum of `5` possible paths...but i'll later update it so that the program can possibly work with all the graphs.

As you can see there are a lot of variables inside this recursive method `--> 4` to move inside `path` and `possiblePath` (row/col), the 2D arrays with `path` containing all the linked nodes and `possiblePath` which will contain all the possible paths from `A` to `B` and finally `distance` that (using `cont`) will update itself with the length of each path so that at the end it can choose the shortest.

This is the output for `findPath` (it iterates `5` times inside the first possible path which is also wrong):

`0 1 2 null null 0 1 2 null null 0 1 2 null null 0 1 2 null null 0 1 2 null null`

Comment: Your method and variable naming makes it hard to provide help. I guess the method you provide is actually `findAllPossiblePaths`? And then you do some post processing to find the path from source to target? You also mention the "output of findPath" but your method is void so how do you get that output?

Comment: @Arcanefoam Yeah the method is really confused, as you said, i want to `findAllPossiblePaths` and then somehow Java will choose the shortest by itself. The output comes from another method which calls `findPath`

Comment: Have you debugged your method to understand where it goes wrong? I would point my finger at the wrong counter (colPoss, rowPoss) being incremented/used.

Comment: @Arcanefoam Yeah the thing is that i know where i'm wrong but don't know how to fix it! : the method starts searching the first path `(0,0) (0,1) (1,2) (2,1)` which output's `0 1 2` . This output is obviously wrong so somehow i need to discard it but not at all : `(0,0) (0,1) (1,2)` are still good but `(2,1)` is not 'cause it has no links with other nodes to get me to my target (9). My goal is to start again the process of finding the shortest path not considering `(2,1)` so that at its second try the output will be `(0,0) (0,1) (1,2) (2,3) (3,4)` and so on..

Comment: where are you storing the edges and in which format ?
usually in the simplest form one takes a node, iterate over its neighbours (with a for-loop), and for each neighbor, makes a recursive call with a path of length +1

Comment: @grodzi edges are stored  here `Integer[][] path` , i really don't know how to iterate recursivly through the array

Comment: I assume you know the neighbours from the current node. You need a recursive function with signature: (node, visitedNodes) => shortestPath . It will return empty array if no shortestPath from node to your targetNode, and must avoid visiting neighbours already in visitedNodes. When the function is called, you list neighbours of the node, and call that function on every valid neighbor. Then you keep the shortest path and return it

Comment: @grodzi For the example in "my set" the node "2" has many links so the recursive function will count as visited each of them until it reaches the link `(2,8)` (which is also the only path possible to get to the target) and that's ok. With this logic after i visited all the nodes before `(1,2)` , they will not be visited again...isn't this a problem?

Comment: yeah, you give a **copy** (like .clone() or someting) of the visited nodes when you recursively call. This way when you have finished exploring a neighbor, you are not impacted by the nodes "it" visited when visiting an other neighbor

Comment: @grodzi so for each node, i save it into another array like `boolean[][] visitedNodes` changing "false" with "true" and at the same time i save it into a `Integer[][] finalPath` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First consider the very basic dfs

Syntax looks like js but I didn't try to run it. Consider it pseudocode.

```
const dfs = node => {
  if (node.value === 9) {
    return console.log('target reached')
  }
  node.children.forEach(child => {
    dfs(child)
  })
}
```

Then you want to avoid **cycles**. In your example I don't think there are any but just do it anyway since you are learning

```
const dfs = (node, visited) => {
  if (node.value === 9) {
    return console.log('target reached')
  }
  if (visited.has(node)) { return console.log('ignore cycle') }

  visited.add(node)

  node.children.forEach(child => {
    dfs(child, visited)
  })

  // clean visited once we are finished exploring current node
  visited.remove(node)
}
dfs({ value: 0 }, new Set()) // use a Set for O(1) access
```

Then you want to know which path you used to reach 9

```
const dfs = (node, visited) => {
  if (node.value === 9) {
    return [node] // return the path
  }
  if (visited.has(node)) { return null }

  visited.add(node)

  let somePath = null
  node.children.forEach(child => {
    const path = dfs(child, visited)
    if (path !== null) {
      // theorically we could stop here but that's not the purpose of illustration
      somePath = [node].concat(path)
    }
  })

  // clean visited once we are finished exploring current node
  visited.remove(node)

  return somePath
}
```

Finally you don't want any path to target but only the shortest one

```
const dfs = (node, visited) => {
  if (node.value === 9) {
    return { size: 0, path: [node] } //return the path AND its size
  }
  if (visited.has(node)) { return { size: Math.infinity, path: null } }

  visited.add(node)

  let best = { size: Math.infinity, path: null }
  node.children.some(child => {
    const { size, path } = dfs(child, visited)
    if (size + distance(node, child) < best.size) {
      best = {
        size: size + distance(node, child),
        path: [node].concat(path)
      }
    }
  })

  // clean visited once we are finished exploring current node
  visited.remove(node)

  return best
}
```

This is by no means efficient but this is a possible way of doing your recursion

```js
const data = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,2],[2,1],[2,3],[3,4],[2,5],[5,6],[6,4],[2,7],[2,8],[8,9]]
const nodes = data.reduce((acc, [a, b]) => {
  acc[a] = acc[a] || { value: a, children: []}
  acc[b] = acc[b] || { value: b, children: []}
  acc[a].children.push(acc[b])
  return acc
}, {})

const dfs = (node, visited) => {
  if (node.value === 9) { return { size: 0, path: [node] } }
  if (visited.has(node)) { return { size: 9001, path: null } }
  visited.add(node)
  let best = { size: 9001, path: null }
  node.children.forEach(child => {
    const { size, path } = dfs(child, visited)
    if (size + 1 < best.size) {
      best = {
        size: size + 1,
        path: [node].concat(path)
      }
    }
  })
  visited.delete(node)
  return best
}

console.log(dfs(nodes[0], new Set()).path.map(x => x.value))
```

I would waste too much time transposing this in java, hope it will be enough so you can come up to a java implem on your own

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow your logic, but favored ArrayLists and Deques over Arrays since we don't know how big they need to be before execution. The main difference from yours is the `currentPath.pollFirst()` which basically takes a step back in the current path when all paths starting at the startNode have been visited. The resulting map has nodes for keys and all paths for that node in the value. This makes it easy to find paths from source to target. As a result of using queues, the end of the paths is always the first element, which also makes it easy to determine if the path ends at the target.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Integer[][] edges = new Integer[][] {
            { 0, 0 },
            { 0, 1 },
            { 1, 2 },
            { 2, 1 },
            { 2, 3 },
            { 3, 4 },
            { 2, 5 },
            { 5, 6 },
            { 6, 4 },
            { 2, 7 },
            { 2, 8 },
            { 8, 9 } };
    Map<Integer, List<List<Integer>>> paths = new HashMap<>();
    for (Integer[] edge : edges) {
        paths.put(edge[0], recusrivePaths(edges, edge[0], new ArrayDeque<>()));
    }
    // Shortest path 0 - 9
    int size = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    List<Integer> shortest = null;
    int source = 0;
    int target = 9;
    for (List<Integer> p : paths.get(source)) {
        if (p.get(0) == target) { // Paths are in reverse order so destination is always first element
            if (p.size() < size) {
                shortest = p;
            }
        }
    }
}

private static List<List<Integer>> recusrivePaths(
    Integer[][] edges,
    Integer startNode,
    Deque<Integer> currentPath) {
    List<List<Integer>> startNodePaths = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer[] edge : edges) {
        Integer targetNode = edge[1];
        // Visit edges that start at the startNode and avoid loops.
        if (edge[0] == startNode
                && targetNode != startNode
                && !currentPath.contains(targetNode)) { 
            // Here comes the recursion, we need to find
            // all paths that start at the target node.
            currentPath.push(targetNode);
            List<List<Integer>> targetPaths = recusrivePaths(edges, targetNode, currentPath);
            for(List<Integer> p : targetPaths) {
                ArrayList<Integer> stitchedPath = new ArrayList<>(p);
                stitchedPath.add(targetNode);
                startNodePaths.add(stitchedPath);
            }
            ArrayList<Integer> targetPath = new ArrayList<>();
            targetPath.add(currentPath.pollFirst());
            startNodePaths.add(targetPath);
        }
    }
    return startNodePaths;
}
```

Note that this method is not efficient as all sub-paths of a path are also paths so there are faster ways to do this. [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) is one of them.

Here is a java.util free version:

```
public class ShortPathPrimitive {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Integer[][] edges = new Integer[][] {
                { 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1 },
                { 1, 2 },
                { 2, 1 },
                { 2, 3 },
                { 3, 4 },
                { 2, 5 },
                { 5, 6 },
                { 6, 4 },
                { 2, 7 },
                { 2, 8 },
                { 8, 9 } };
        Integer [][] paths = new Integer[0][];        
        for (Integer[] edge : edges) {
            Integer[][] sourcePaths = recursivePaths(edges, edge[0], new Integer[0]);
            // Add the source node to the path
            for (Integer[] p : sourcePaths) {
                p = addToPath(p, edge[0]);
                paths = addToPaths(paths, p);
            }
        }
        // Shortest path 0 - 9
        int size = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        Integer[] shortest = null;
        int source = 0;
        int target = 9;
        for (Integer[] p : paths) {
            if (p[0] == target && p[p.length-1] == source) { // Paths are in reverse order so destination is always first element
                if (p.length < size) {
                    shortest = p;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(shortest));
    }

    private static Integer [][] recursivePaths(
        Integer[][] edges,
        Integer startNode,
        Integer[] currentPath) {
        Integer [][] startNodePaths = new Integer[0][];
        for (Integer[] edge : edges) {
            Integer targetNode = edge[1];
            // Visit edges that start at the startNode and avoid loops.
            if (edge[0] == startNode
                    && targetNode != startNode
                    && !inPath(currentPath, targetNode)) { 
                // Here comes the recursion, we need to find
                // all paths that start at the target node.
                currentPath = pustToPath(currentPath, targetNode);
                Integer [][] targetPaths = recursivePaths(edges, targetNode, currentPath);
                for(Integer [] p : targetPaths) {
                    Integer[] stitchedPath = p.clone();
                    stitchedPath = addToPath(stitchedPath, targetNode);
                    startNodePaths= addToPaths(startNodePaths, stitchedPath);
                }
                // Create a path from the source to the target
                Integer[] targetPath = new Integer[1];
                targetPath[0] = currentPath[0];
                currentPath = pollFirstPath(currentPath);
                // And add it to the paths
                startNodePaths = addToPaths(startNodePaths, targetPath);
            }
        }
        return startNodePaths;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the node is in the path
     * @param path  the path
     * @param node  the node
     * @return true if the node is in the path
     */
    private static boolean inPath(Integer[] path, Integer node) {
        return Arrays.asList(path).contains(node);
    }

    /**
     * Push the node to the beginning of the Array, i.e. simulate queue push
     * @param path  the path to modify
     * @param node  the node to add
     * @return the modified path
     */
    private static Integer[] pustToPath(final Integer[] path, final Integer node){
        Integer[] temp = path.clone();
        Integer[] result = new Integer[path.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, result, 1, temp.length);
        result[0] = node;
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Add a node to the end of the path.
     * @param path  the path to modify
     * @param node  the node to add
     * @return the modified path
     */
    private static Integer[] addToPath(final Integer[] path, final Integer node){
        Integer[] temp = path.clone();
        Integer[] result = new Integer[path.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, result, 0, temp.length);
        result[temp.length] = node;
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Poll (remove) the first element of the path
     * @param path  the path to modify
     * @return the modified path
     */
    private static Integer[] pollFirstPath(final Integer[] path) {
        Integer[] temp = path.clone();
        Integer[] result = new Integer[path.length - 1];
        System.arraycopy(temp, 1, result, 0, temp.length-1);
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Add a path to an array of paths
     * @param paths the array of paths to modify
     * @param path  the path to add
     * @return a copy of the paths with the path added
     */
    private static Integer[][] addToPaths(final Integer[][] paths, final Integer[] path) {
        Integer[][] temp = paths.clone();
        Integer[][] result = new Integer[paths.length + 1][];
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, result, 0, temp.length);
        result[temp.length] = path;
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: is there a way to solve this problem without using java.util classes?

Comment: @EddyIT yes, the Map can be easily replaced by a 2 dimensional array as in your first attempt. The queue part is harder, mostly because you don't know before hand how many paths (and their size) you will find so you can not create the arrays from the beginning. You can create new ones, increasing their size as you go, but gets verbose. Why cant you use util classes?

Comment: not very familiar with java.util ... switched from python to java and i'm totally new to all the packages